# how to insert long space after title using html?

Tags: html

i'm using html with title tag.

Eg:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Title Name  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;                                                                      </title>
  </head>
</html>
```

in this i want long space after "Title Name" using html code.
i tried to use `&nbsp;` but it is too length to put the code. any other alternative to space after title.

Comment: Why? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've edited your post to show the code. Please take note that your markup is invalid - the `</html>` and `</head>` are not in the correct order.

Comment: maybe its a typo, but `</head>` should come before `</html>`

Comment: Please explain more what is too length?? to put what the code where???

Comment: There is no text at the end of the space, so how do you know the spaces are not there? I tried this in chrome  dev tools and it works `html5 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; - how to insert long space after title using html? - Stack Overflow`

Comment: While I am not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish with that, I am sure there is a better way to do it with CSS.

Comment: how the hel* with css, what you people talk about? i want to know how to edit title with css please :D lol

Comment: All, here is my requirement. i just open the modal window with title. after that, in modal window suffix webpage dialog is appended. i didnot remove this. so i tried to space after title. any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you just want to avoid writing **long** and much of `&nbsp;` codes. And if you use PHP then i suggest you to do it like this:

```
<title>Start <?php str_repeat("&nbsp;", 30); ?> End</title>
```

Otherwise i see no problem in using much `&nbsp;` like you did.

Comment: sorry, i do not want PHP. only HTML with javascript.

Comment: then i do not understand what are you trying to accomplish and where is the problem in how you provided in question...&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

Comment: This will produce 20 of those characters in javascript: `Array(20).join(String.fromCharCode(160))` it should be noted that Chrome strips them out though. You can use `document.title` to set the title with javascript

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see why length would be an issue, but you can use actual NO-BREAK SPACE U+00A0 characters instead of the entity reference `&nbsp;`, e.g.

```
<title>Title Name                                                        </title>
```

Comment: @ jukka what is NO-BREAK SPACE U+00A0 ? how can i implement

Comment: It is the character denoted by `&nbsp;`. If you don’t know how to type it in your authoring environment, you can e.g. cut and paste the string from my example above.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding FeRtoll's answer and since you don't want to use PHP, you could use the JavaScript library which ports some PHP functions to JS.

http://phpjs.org/functions/str_repeat/

Answer (score 1):

What about `&nbsp;`, `&thinsp;`, `&ensp;` and `&emsp;`?